# Moodle file upload error while upload assignments

Tags: php, moodle

When students uploading assignments they are getting following message "Cannot create local file pool directories.Please verify permissions in dataroot " randomly.The file they uploaded is available but could not find why that message shown to them.The folders having full permission.Can someone assist on this?

Comment: You probably just need to `chmod` the directory to give it read/write permission

Comment: The folders having the following permissions drwxrwxr-x . wil this make any issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a directory (d), owner can read write execute (rwx), group can also rwx, everyone else can only read and execute. Find out which user PHP is running as `exec('whoami')`, and either change the owner, or add the php user to the group. Last option is make the folder writable for everyone (no!)